# Sum and Percentage by using LookupSet

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a SQL report that counts the number of instances of a field. I am pulling this into a summary report. This works using the Lookupset function. However, I want to take the total of this column and find the percentage of the rows.
For example:

Preferred Employer = Yes, Preferred Employer = No
I want to be able to add a Percentage Column next to the count column that would show the Percentage of each row.
The end result would total 100

[image]

Count formula:
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!pscode.Value, Fields!pscode.Value, Fields!PrefCnt.Value, "PrefEmployer"), vbCrLF + vbCrLF)

Total:
=RunningValue(Fields!PrefCnt.Value,Sum,"PrefEmployer")

Percent:

=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!PrefCnt.Value,Sum,"PrefEmployer") <> 0, Join(LookupSet(Fields!pscode.Value, Fields!pscode.Value, Fields!PrefCnt.Value, "PrefEmployer"), vbCrLF + vbCrLF)/RunningValue(Fields!PrefCnt.Value,Sum,"PrefEmployer")*100,0)

Results
[image]

```
SELECT
vt.pscode as pscode,
vt.PrefEmpl as PrefEmpl,
SUM(vt.PrefCnt) as PrefCnt
FROM
(
SELECT
  rtrim(p.sAddr1) + ' (' + rtrim(p.sCode) + ')' pscode,
  isnull(ltrim(lb.sPrefEmployer), 'No') PrefEmpl,
  count(lb.sPrefEmployer) PrefCnt
FROM
  property p (nolock)
  INNER JOIN tenant t (nolock) on p.hMy = t.hProperty
  INNER JOIN Leasebut28 lb (nolock) on t.hMyPerson = lb.hCode
  INNER JOIN tenstatus ts (nolock) ON (t.istatus = ts.istatus)
WHERE
  (
    t.dtMoveIn <= '2022-08-22'
    and (
      t.dtMoveOut > '2022-08-22'
      or t.dtMoveOut is null
    )
  )
  AND ts.Status in ('Current', 'Future', 'Notice')
  AND t.sUnitCode NOT IN ('COMAREA', 'WAIT')
  AND t.sUnitCode NOT LIKE ('NONRES%')
  AND lb.sCorp <> 'Yes'
  and p.scode = 'carcen2'
GROUP BY
  rtrim(p.sAddr1) + ' (' + rtrim(p.sCode) + ')',
  lb.sPrefEmployer
UNION ALL
SELECT
  rtrim(p.sAddr1) + ' (' + rtrim(p.sCode) + ')' pscode,
  isnull(ltrim(b.sPrefEmployer), 'No') PrefEmpl,
  count(b.sPrefEmployer) PrefCnt
FROM
  room r (nolock)
  INNER JOIN tenant t (nolock) ON (t.hmyperson = r.hmytenant)
  INNER JOIN unit u (nolock) ON (u.hmy = t.hunit)
  INNER JOIN unittype ut (nolock) on (ut.hMy = u.hUnitType)
  INNER JOIN tenstatus ts (nolock) ON (t.istatus = ts.istatus)
  INNER JOIN property p (nolock) ON (p.hmy = t.hproperty)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RoomBut1 b (nolock) ON (r.hMyPerson = b.hCode)
WHERE
  isnull(r.dtmoveout, '01/01/2400') > Getdate()
  AND (
    t.dtMoveIn <= '2022-08-22'
    and (
      t.dtMoveOut > '2022-08-22'
      or t.dtMoveOut is null
    )
  )
  AND r.sRelationship <> 'Guarantor'
  AND ts.Status in ('Current', 'Future', 'Notice')
  AND t.sUnitCode NOT IN ('COMAREA', 'WAIT')
  AND t.sUnitCode NOT LIKE ('NONRES%')
  AND r.bOccupant <> -1
  and p.scode = 'carcen2'
 GROUP BY
  rtrim(p.sAddr1) + ' (' + rtrim(p.sCode) + ')',
  b.sPrefEmployer
) vt
GROUP BY
vt.pscode,
vt.PrefEmpl
Order by 2
```

Dataset:
[image]

Comment: What does your data look like (the results of the dataset query)? Please edit your question and show a sample as there might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. It shows an error in the 'Pct' column.

Comment: You still need to show a sample of your data, we can't see what you are working with. If you run the dataset query what output do you get? That's what is being passed to the report so that's the bit I need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood this but if you just want to get the Yes vs No % share of each pscode then you could just change your query from

```
SELECT
vt.pscode as pscode,
vt.PrefEmpl as PrefEmpl,
SUM(vt.PrefCnt) as PrefCnt
FROM
(
...
... existing subquery here
...
) vt
GROUP BY
vt.pscode,
vt.PrefEmpl
Order by 2
```

to

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    vt.pscode as pscode,
    vt.PrefEmpl as PrefEmpl,
    SUM(vt.PrefCnt) OVER(PARTITION BY vt.pscode, vt.PrefEmpl) as PrefCnt
    CAST(SUM(vt.PrefCnt) OVER(PARTITION BY vt.pscode, vt.PrefEmpl) as float)
       / CAST(SUM(vt.PrefCnt) OVER(PARTITION BY vt.pscode) as float)
       as PrefCntPercent
FROM
(
...
... existing subquery here
...
) vt
Order by 2
```

Comment: Thank you Alan. I tried that but I got zero for the calculation

Comment: I've made a small change to cast the values to floats before the division happens, this might fix it.

Comment: No problem. Could you please mark the answer as accepted (the check box to the left below the vote up/down buttons). This helps others find answers to similar questions.